# Connect Canon Selphy CP1200 via USB - Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, canon

I am trying to hook up a Canon Selphy CP1200 via USB but just can't get it to work. I can see the printer when I run `lsusb` ... `Bus 001 Device 016: ID 04a9:32b1 Canon, Inc. SELPHY CP1200` but I don't have the option to install it as a printer. I have tried using both the gnome printer manager and Turbo Print. Both have drivers for the printer but they can't seem to detect that it's available. Is there a way to point my system to that USB device specifically? I have gutenprint 5.3.1 and CUPS 2.2.10 installed

I ran `journalctl --follow` and then plugged in the printer. Here is what I see

```
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps kernel: usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 45 using xhci_hcd
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04a9, idProduct=32b1, bcdDevice= 0.01
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps kernel: usb 1-2: Product: SELPHY CP1200
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps kernel: usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Canon
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps kernel: usblp 1-2:1.0: usblp2: USB Bidirectional printer dev 45 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04A9 pid 0x32B1
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps mtp-probe[7073]: checking bus 1, device 45: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps mtp-probe[7073]: bus: 1, device: 45 was not an MTP device
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps systemd[1]: Starting Configure Plugged-In Printer...
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps mtp-probe[7092]: checking bus 1, device 45: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps mtp-probe[7092]: bus: 1, device: 45 was not an MTP device
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps udev-configure-printer[7091]: add usb-001-045
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps udev-configure-printer[7091]: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps udev-configure-printer[7091]: MFG:Canon MDL:SELPHY CP1200 SERN:- serial:Z816080312570414
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps systemd-resolved[1112]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps systemd-resolved[1112]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps systemd-resolved[1112]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct 14 18:54:10 ryan-xps systemd-resolved[1112]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct 14 18:54:15 ryan-xps kernel: usblp2: removed
Oct 14 18:54:15 ryan-xps systemd-resolved[1112]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct 14 18:54:15 ryan-xps systemd-resolved[1112]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Oct 14 18:54:17 ryan-xps udev-configure-printer[7091]: URI of detected printer: ipp://localhost:0/ipp/print, normalized: ipp localhost 0 ipp print
Oct 14 18:54:17 ryan-xps udev-configure-printer[7091]: URI of print queue: cnijnet:/84-BA-3B-09-E8-FB, normalized: cnijnet 84 ba 3b 09 e8 fb
Oct 14 18:54:17 ryan-xps udev-configure-printer[7091]: Launched ippusbxd, command line "ippusbxd -l -v 04a9 -m 32b1 -s Z816080312570414 -P 60000", port 60000, process 7144
Oct 14 18:54:17 ryan-xps systemd[1]: Started Configure Plugged-In Printer.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. It seems that it was a conflict between CUPS and lpusb. The solution was to disable lpusb by running `sudo rmmod usblp`. I'm not sure if this has and negative side effects, but it seems to have solved my issue. Once I did this I was able to go to http://localhost:631 and add the printer. There are some details about this problem here https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=545288